# How to bind directive's scope to its property function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider the following angular directive:

```
<my-datepicker 
     ng-model="myController.user.dob"
     min="1960-01-01" 
     max="2017-12-31"
     isValid="myController.validateDOB(myController.user.dob)"
></my-datepicker>
```

In this case `validateDOB` function will be called in the scope of the controller. I want to call it in the scope of the directive to be able to use its min and max properties. I tried to do this:

```
<my-datepicker 
     ng-model="myController.user.dob"
     min="1960-01-01" 
     max="2017-12-31"
     isValid="myController.validateDOB.call(this, myController.user.dob)"
></my-datepicker>
```

which fails with an exception:
`Error: [$parse:isecff] Referencing call, apply or bind in Angular expressions is disallowed!`
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Directive have function reference binding which you can call whatever why you need.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has provided `'&'` binding option by that you can call conttroller's function inside directive's function.

**Parent Controller**

```
app.controller('myCntrl', function($scope) {
    var myController = this;

    myController.validateDOB = function(dob) {
        // some code
    };
})
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDatepicker, function() {
    return {
        template: '<button ng-click="handleClick()">Click</button>',
        scope: {
            validateDob: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.handleClick = function() {
                $scope.validateDob({dob: 'dob'})
            };
        }
    }
})
```

**Usage:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <my-datepicker validate-dob="myController.validateDOB(dob)"></my-datepicker>
</div>
```